# Consequences of Dynamically rewriting a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, you can rewrite a function, like so:

```
function foo() { 
   setTimeout(function() {
        alert('sup stallion');
        foo = function() { //rewrite foo to nolonger wait 4 seconds to alert.
             alert('sup stallion');
        }
   }, 4000);
}
```

Obviously this is a contrived example, but is there anything conceptually wrong with this approach (<strike>other than a race condition</strike>).

Comment: Why would there be a race condition?  There aren't multiple simultaneous threads running the JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Self modifying code can be confusing, and hard to debug, so it's generally avoided.

Other than that there is no problem, and no race condition either.

Comment: This is not self-modifying code. It's doing a well-defined thing: replacing the binding `foo` which holds a function, with a new function.

Comment: I.e. to be more clear: the original function is not being destructively changed into another function; only a reference to that function is being lost, which is very different. Modifying the variable binding environment is not the same as modifying code in place.

Comment: @Kaz: Yes, it's not strictly self modifying, but the effect is the same, so it can be just as hard to follow. If you want to change the function you should declare it as a variable from the start, if it's declared using regular function syntax it's generally not expected to change.

Answer (score 4):

One thing I noticed while testing your code. Consider this:

```
setInterval(foo, 6000);
```

Function `foo` is being passed to `setInterval` before it was modified, and the *original* `foo` will run every 6 seconds, even after the binding has been updated.

On the other hand, the code below will run the original function only on the first call (which updates the binding). Subsequent calls will invoke the updated version:

```
setInterval(function(){foo();}, 6000);
```

Looks obvious, but could be hard to debug...

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic function rewriting can be used as a form of [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization), however there is a catch:

```
function Foo() {...}
Foo.prototype = {
    bar: function () {
        //some initialized variables to close over
        var a, b, c, ...;
        Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
            //do stuff with variables
        };
        Foo.prototype.bar.call(this);
    }
};
```

While this code is relatively straight-forward to understand, and would be used as:

```
var f = new Foo();
f.bar(); //initializes `bar` function
f.bar(); //uses initialized `bar` function
```

it has a hidden issue:

```
var f = new Foo(),
    g = {};
//passing by reference before the function was initialized will behave poorly
g.bar = f.bar;
f.bar(); //initializes `bar` function
g.bar(); //re-initializes `bar` function
f.bar(); //uses initialized `bar` function
g.bar(); //re-initializes `bar` function
```

It's for this reason that any initialization needed for a function is typically done using a module pattern:

```
function Foo() {...}
Foo.prototype = {
    bar: (function () {
        var a, b, c, ..., fn;
        //some initialized variables to close over
        fn = function () {
            //do stuff with variables
        };
        return fn;
    }())
};
```

The module pattern has the disadvantage of calling the initialization code immediately, but wont have the issues associated with the function reference.